# Xamarin.Forms can't convert TTF file in stream

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, stream, truetype

I'm working on Xamarin.Forms app with help of Syncfusion and want to add Cyrillic support in PDF drawing.I download  `ArialUnicodeMS.tff` added the file in Shared Project in Resources folder and added Build Action `Embedded Resource` and also added
 `[assembly: ExportFont("ArialUnicodeMS.ttf", Alias = "ArialUni")]` in `AssemblyInfo.cs`. But Syncfusion Pdf Drawing want to access to the TTF file by `Stream`.

This is my code:

```
var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(EmbeddedFont)).Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyAppName.ArialUnicodeMS.ttf");
PdfFont font = new PdfTrueTypeFont(stream, 14);
```

But my string is always `null`. Where i'm getting wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the code below to get the stream from the Embeded resource.

```
   var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceName = "App28.Trashtalk.ttf";
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
```

Comment: the problem was you must add the Font to PdfGrid

Answer (score 0):

The resource is missing.

Most likely it is one of these 3 issues:

- the name `"MyAppName.ArialUnicodeMS.ttf"` has a typo.
- the resource is not embedded in the `typeof(EmbeddedFont)).Assembly` assembly.
- you have not set the parameter `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`. This is part of the `EmbeddedFont` project and acts on the `ArialUnicodeMS.ttf` resource.

To verify which names are available, you can use:

```
string resourceNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

Comment: whit this line: 
 Stream f = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("FinansovoPregledi.ArialUnicodeMS.ttf"); -> fill the stream but again on pdf not showing the cyrillic characters(it's empty where are cyrillic characters)

Comment: If the stream is not empty, it must be something with the `PdfTrueTypeFont` call.

Comment: Yeah but he accept stream i convert in to stream, because previous was cant't find the resource to read from.